# Not able to play mp3 in my android app

Tags: android

I am developing a online mp3 streaming app in android. When i use direct link, it will play ,but when I uses the given below link, Its not playing.

Here is my code

```
String ulr="http://hls1.addictradio.net/addictrock_hls/playlist.m3u8";

play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url2);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
           // mediaPlayer.start();




        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think there is a problem regarding file format.Try with some other link of `mp3` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your url `http://hls1.addictradio.net/addictrock_hls/playlist.m3u8` i think its a playlist file.

It may because of the format of the video which is `playlist.m3u8` and it may not be supporting by android.

Check [Supported Media Formates](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Answer (score 0):

ulr != url2. Are you sure you are passing the correct variable? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    String ulr="http://hls1.addictradio.net/addictrock_hls/playlist.m3u8";


play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
                 mp.setDataSource(ulr);
                 mp.prepare();
                 mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```